# Assert.AreEqual - Null vs Empty String

Tags: c#, nunit

Take the following example:

```
string x = null;
var y = String.Empty;
Assert.AreEqual(x, y);             // test fails!
Assert.AreEqual(x ?? "", y ?? ""); // passes, but ugly!
```

I understand that null and empty string aren't the same but for my particular application these are basically the same. My question is - are there any shortcuts that will treat null and empty string the same way? Otherwise I am faced with using the null coalescing operator all over (a bit ugly!)

**Background**

For a background on where this question comes from, I'm writing integration tests for a project. Basically I'm saving values to a database, then loading them again and checking that the two match. Some values, when saved are empty strings, but when loaded via EF they are coming back as null values. This causes a number of my integration test to fail.

**EDIT/NOTE** - The values I am using for testing are randomized. That means sometimes the value will be empty but other times they will be filled in. That in mind, I would have to use the null coalescent on every single string comparison (hence the question of an abbreviated way of doing this).

Comment: @reggaeguitar If you read the question I'm not asking about string comparison. I'm asking about how to abbreviate an nUnit call.

Comment: you're right, I'm sorry. I would just make a method that contains the null coalescing operator and call that in your Asserts

Comment: I'm not sure whether nunit supports `IEqualityComparer`, if yes you can pass custom comparer. Otherwise create custom comparer and use it like `Assert.IsTrue(yourComparer.Equals(x,y))`

Comment: What about an extension method taking the X an Y as parameter and encapsulating the assert ?

Comment: `Assert.AreEqual(x + "", y + "");` would be two bytes less ugly :).

Answer (score 4):

Drew: AlexD was on track, although he did not have it fully ferreted out. Example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AreSame("", ""));
        Console.WriteLine(AreSame("", null));
        Console.WriteLine(AreSame(null, ""));
        Console.WriteLine(AreSame(null, null));

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static bool AreSame(string x, string y)
    {
        return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) == string.IsNullOrEmpty(y));
    }
```

In your case, you can use

```
Assert.AreEqual(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x), string.IsNullOrEmpty(y));
```

Or

```
Assert.IsTrue(AreSame(x, y));
```

Ugly? Sure, but you can at least abstract the ugliness out a bit. Ugly as

```
Assert.AreEqual(x ?? "", y ?? ""); // passes, but ugly!
```

??? Not sure. Depends on how you look at it.

Comment: But x and y *could* also have values. Maybe the compare would be `string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) == string.IsNullOrEmpty(y) || x == y`?